# Vue URL Updating but Component is not

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Having an issue with my url updating but the page not.

From the home page, I display a list of `projects`. Clicking a project will take you to `"website.com/project/project-1"` and everything works as intended.

However, at the bottom of that page, I again show a list. This list is the same as homepage, with same functionality. But the problem is, is that it will update the url to `"website.com/project/project-2"` but the page will not re-render or change.

An example of my code
My current router-path of the component.

```
path: '/project/:project_slug',
name: 'ProjectPage',
component: ProjectPage
```

My Router Link from the project page to the new project page

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'ProjectPage', params: {project_slug: projectHighlightSlug} }">
   <h4 class="header-17 semibold">{{projectTitle}}</h4>
</router-link>
```

Update

This is my current method/watch section

```
methods: {
  goToProject() {
    this.$router.push({
     name: 'ProjectPage', 
     params: {project_slug: this.projectHighlightSlug}
  })
 },
},
watch:{
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
'$route'(to, from) {
  this.goToProject();
  }
}
```

However, the to,from is "defined but never used" and clicking my button to call goToProject() gives me the error;
"You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "$route""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to watch the routes to update your page. see code below

```
watch:{
     '$route' (to, from) {
         this.goToProject()
         // call your method here that updates your page
      }
},
```

source [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: Ah ok i see!

Are you able to give an example? I tried to follow the docs and a few other sites and do not fully understand the "to, from" and how to dynamically call them.

Comment: how did you update your page ? what function are you calling out ?

Comment: goToProject() {
      this.$router.push({name: 'ProjectPage', params: {project_slug: this.projectHighlightSlug}})
},

Comment: then you have to put that inside that curly braces, nothing more

Comment: tell me if it does not help you yet

Comment: Do you mean within the $route(to, from) curly braces?

And, if so do i call the method in there? as when I just have the "goToProject" in there, it says to and from are defined but never used. As well as goToProject() "not defined"

Comment: Ok great! That solves the issue of not defined.

However, the (to,from) still show as defined but never used. I tried removing and just having $route() and got an infinite loop error

Comment: No it's fine, dont remove it, it will not affect your code

Comment: Certainly getting me closer, i just updated my code with the issue I am running in to/how it is now set-up. Maybe I have done something wrong.

Comment: "You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "$route""

Comment: did you copied my answer ?

Comment: yup copied it again to be sure but no luck

Comment: Basically because you calling again the goToProject functiion, what i mean is that the function that updates the component it self not that one

Comment: In your mounted or created what functions your are calling ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206528/discussion-between-kjparker-and-qonvex620).

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the Vue Router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes), when the url the user navigates to uses the same component, it uses the same instance of that component. The docs therefore recommend to listen to $route changes or to use the `beforeRouteUpdate` navigation guard.

Comment: Ah ok i see, that would make sense as to why it only changes the URL.

Are you able to give an example? I tried to follow the docs and a few other sites and do not fully understand the "to, from" and how to dynamically call them.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a key to your router view, and the component will refresh once the url path changes.

```
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath">
```